# Textbook for Groups with Operators

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation

There are many great introductory textbooks on group theory and operator theory separately. Which textbook is good for [groups with operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_with_operators), or $\Omega$-groups?

Comment: Are you looking for stuff like abstract harmonic analysis or group C* algebras?

Comment: No, I'm only looking for the basic theory and properties of groups with operators.

Comment: This is really unclear. Do you mean that you want to study groups via operators? Like how you can study groups with matrices in the finite group case?

Comment: I would like to study the algebraic structure of $(G, \Omega)$ where $G$ is a group and the operator $\Omega$ is an action set on the group. So, $\Omega \times G \rightarrow G$. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_with_operators) is its wiki page.

Comment: Okay I would not consider this operator theory (as most people know it) based on that Wiki article. Operations on a set $\neq$ operator theory. Fixed the tags to match.

Comment: Okay thanks for the edit.

Comment: No problem! Hopefully someone more knowledgeable can chime in.

Comment: There's a chapter on $\Omega$-groups in Robinson's *"A Course in the Theory of Groups (Second Edition)"*. It's far from introductory though.

Comment: There's a whole chapter on groups with operators in Jacobson's _Lectures in Abstract Algebra_ (Volume 1). Rotman _briefly_ discusses them in his _Introduction to the Theory of Groups_, but covers a lot of ground by saying only the results, and leaving the proofs as straightforward generalizations of similar proofs for modules.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your recommendations!